# Swift - 1 screen to another screen

Tags: ios, swift

I have set you my UI for both screens and I don't want to do the connect the screens in main.storyboard. I want to click a button and it will take to  that screen, I will do the fade animations and stuff like that later. I just need to know how to go to one screen to the next screen when I press a button. I can give an example of what I am talking about down below.

Example: In flappy bird before you start the game it tell you to tap on the screen, then when you tap the text fades out. That is what I want to do with my game. I am not sure if that is another screen or if that is 1 view that makes certain labels disappear once the screen is tapped.

**My MainMenuViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit


class MainMenuViewController: UIViewController {


    var mainMenuScene: MainMenuScene!



    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!


    @IBAction func playButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        mainMenuScene.playButtonPressed(sender)
    }


    @IBAction func playerButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("player")
    }

    @IBAction func LeaderboardButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("leaderboard")
    }

    @IBAction func shopButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        println("shop")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        //set up game screens

        // Configure the view

        // store a ref

        // Create and configure the scene
        mainMenuScene?.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        // Present the scene
    }



    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
        } else {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

**My MainMenuScene:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class MainMenuScene: SKScene {

    var movingGround: PPMovingGround!
    var square1: PPSquare1!
    var wallGen: PPWallGen!

    var isStarted = false

    var playButton: UIButton!



    func playButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        start()

    }


    func start() {
        isStarted = true

        square1.stop()
        movingGround.start()
        wallGen.startGenWallsEvery(1)
    }


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {


    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    }

}
```

I want to connect this code to my GameScene File. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what you're aiming for, since you don't want to do work with the **Main.storyboard** directly, you could do this:

```
presentViewController(YourNextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

you would call that in the `ViewController` you are currently in to get to the next one.

Let's say you are on the *main screen*, as you said in *Flappy Bird*, when you tap the button, it could change to a different **View Controller**

My tip would be to nest this method in a function, so you can call it in a `gameStart` function, like so:

```
func changeViewControllers() {
  presentViewController(GameViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

then call this in your `gameStart()`:

```
func gameStart() {
  changeViewControllers()
  //other code
}

//=====================================================================
```

Alright, I'm going to help you get to another view when you tap your play button, add the following code:

```
@IBAction func playButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    mainMenuScene.playButtonPressed(sender)
}
```

Comment: this is kinda what I want it to do, but take a look at this video and then you will understand exactly what I want. (Video in Objective-C, I don't know obj-c) Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h98VmYaZ8Vw

Comment: Can you take a look at the video above and help me write that in swift, as I don't know objective-c .

Comment: To help you write the whole thing, that would defeat the purpose of you learning. :) Is there a particular section you are having trouble on? @Paul654321

Comment: No, not the whole thing xD. I will update my question and I will put the code I have so far, so then you can help me connect them together. If you have time of course :D

Comment: Sure, let's see what you've got @Paul654321

Comment: Is there a particular part you have questioning on? @Paul654321

Comment: yes, connecting both of my MainMenu files to my GameScene

Comment: When you run this, what do you see? @Paul654321

Comment: I see my main menu, but when I click on the play button it tells me `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_l386_INVOP, subcode=0x0` I think that means that I have nothing in my sender, as in my MainMenuScene I did not tell it what to do

Comment: I have that bit of code in my MainMenuViewController but it does not work.

Comment: Here's a simple fix, if you're just trying to get from one *view* to another, just control drag from your button to your intended *view*, in your ***Main.storyboard*** @Paul654321

Comment: yes but then I wont be able to change the animation, will I?

Comment: It won't go right into it like the video, unfortunately, but I highly recommend studying a little objective-c if you want to turn that objective-c code into swift, the languages are just syntactical, meaning they do the same exact thing @Paul654321